# why is this prepare statement vulnerable

Tags: sql, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I am learning about sql-injection and I understand that the prepare statement can protect against it. I had the example below as one of the vulnerable usage of prepare statement but there was no explanation on why. below is the code

```
PreparedStatement psProblem =Connection.prepareStatement( "SELECT user,password, FROM    tbl_user," + userinput.addTableName + " WHERE (user=?)" );
```

Comment: What's your best guess why this is vulnerable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any SQL statement with unsanitized user input is vulnerable for the same reason: the user can input a string that would terminate your SQL early, and replace it with a SQL of its own.

For example, entering something like `tbl_user WHERE 1=0; DROP TABLE tbl_user;--` will drop your user table: the resultant SQL would look like this:

```
SELECT user,password, FROM tbl_user,tbl_user WHERE 1=0; DROP TABLE tbl_user;--WHERE (user=?)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     |                                                    |                  |
Your original query does nothing because of its condition |                  |
                                                          |                  |
                                                 The attack payload          |
                                                                             |
                                                           Commented out portion
```

Comment: ok.. this means that the prepare statement is also vulnerable whenever it receives unsanitized input? the distinction between data an code is still done by the programmer

Comment: @eskoba Absolutely. If any part of your SQL is produced automatically from unsanitized user input, it does not matter if it is a prepared statement or not: a user with enough knowledge about the inner structure of your tables would be able to break it with a high degree of probability. Perhaps a blunt attack like I show above would fail because your code expects certain fields; a SQL expert would be able to "tuck in" an attack statement into your SQL.